# iPhone Xs running iOS v13.3 not showing up in develop menu in Safari v13.0.4 on Mac OS Catalina v10.15.2

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, safari, web-inspector

I realize there are several posts that cover this issue, however the problem seems to persist with every update to iOS and/or MacOS, and it is happening yet again.
Furthermore, past solutions posted on SO do not resolve this issue, and Apple's support site does not provide an answer either.

**Problem:** iPhone model Xs running iOS v13.3 not showing up in develop menu in Safari v13.0.4 on Mac OS Catalina v10.15.2

**What i have tried in the following order, which has worked in the past but is not working today:**

*Note: Yes, some of these steps may be irrelevant, but i did all of them anyway.*

1. *Disconnect* iPhone from Mac
2. iPhone and Mac: Clear cache and history in Safari
3. iPhone and Mac: Quit Safari
4. iPhone: Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Web Inspector (toggle off)
5. iPhone: Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings (reset)
6. iPhone: Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location and Privacy settings (reset)
7. iPhone: Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Web Inspector (toggle on)
8. *Connect* iPhone to Mac
9. iPhone: prompt appears to "Trust this computer", select (yes)
10. Mac: open Finder window -> select my iPhone in sidebar -> *if prompted to 'Trust'* -> select (trust)
11. Mac: launch Safari, select "Develop" menu -> **Device does not appear**

**I can confirm that my hardware is OK** *[Macbook pro and iPhone cable]* since i have successfully tested connecting an older iPhone 7 running an older version of iOS 12.4.1. The older iPhone shows up in the Safari develop menu OK without issue.

Can anyone explain why this problem continues to persist and/or provide other options to try in-order to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue. The only thing that worked for me was installing [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/) and accessing my device from the Develop menu within there instead.